# How should I be flagging bad posts?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, migration

There are a number of questions that look something like:

> halp meeeee!!! i cant conect 2 facebook but im tried my passwords a milion times

I'm not quoting any specific post. But I think it's pretty obvious which posts fit into this description. There's a significant amount that are posted on SO daily.

This one, for example, is about Facebook, so I consider it to be about "general computing", which is part of the migration text for SuperUser. So, I will usually use that as my flag reason for posts like these.

Disregarding the fact that the content may be off-topic on SU (according to the comments, it is), many of these posts are crap that shouldn't be migrated to any SE site (Yahoo Answers would be the ideal location `:)`).

Should I use the "Questions about general computing ... **Super User**." flag reason* on crap that I think should just be deleted? Or another reason entirely? If the entire question was edited, it could be a valuable Super User question (theoretically, the origin of the problem in my example could have been a firewall, which would make it probably more on-topic for SU). Obviously, nobody's going to edit it, so am I wasting people's time flagging like this?

Is there any chance that flagging like this will cause the crap to just be moved to another SE site? I'm not familiar with how migration works.

---

## * Edit:

There are two similar menus.

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on **Super User**.

and

> belongs on superuser.com
>
> Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users

It's clear now that the menu I was using was not the "migration" one, because I was using the first one, not the second.

The UI is unintuitive and should be fixed to be more clear.

This menu item gives the impression that I will be selecting migration choices:

> off-topic because… **(too old to migrate)**
>
> This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

I thought that this menu was an overflow menu of migration choices:

> This question belongs on **another** site in the Stack Exchange network

(I know I ignored a couple of signs, such as the fact that they both list the same sites. Because I always came to the REAL migration menu looking for `Questions about code quality should be asked on Code Review`,  it didn't come to mind.)

Comment: Bad posts? No, the rule is we don't migrate crap.

Comment: If you mean the _close reason_ that just _mentions_ Super User, however, and not the "Belongs on another site" > "Super User" flag, then _that one_ would be appropriate. But the "Belongs on another site" one isn't. From the wording of your question, I'm inclined to believe you're picking the "general computing" close reason, and not the actual migration flag.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated/91446#91446

Comment: If someone migrates a question like that I'm going to come back from the mod dead and punch them through the internets.

Comment: I think you should clarify your question.  You specifically mention "migration" but your description of the flag sounds a lot more like the off-topic reason `Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User` (which isn't about migration).  Can you be specific about which flag you are actually using?

Comment: Such a question (however good it is) doesn't belong on [su] anyway "Websites or web services like Facebook and Twitter are off topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)". A **good** question about facebook would be on topic on [WebApps.SE].

Comment: @Kendra Thank you! The problem is that I ***thought* I was migrating**. The UI is conspiring against me.

Comment: I had thought that might be the case, given your wording. Glad we could clear that up, and yes, you _should definitely be closing questions like that._ They're off-topic and, as you said yourself, bad. Use the one you're using now, as that one is definitely correct in these situations.

Comment: @Laurel if you want to request a feature to change the phrasing or clarify that it isn't "migration", you should put it in a separate post.

Comment: Regarding your recent edit, asking for a change to the UI is a completely different question, so you should edit that suggestion out, clarify your original to explain you _don't_ mean migrating (this can be done just by quoting the close reason and saying that's what you've been using), and ask a new "feature-request" for your UI change suggestion.

Comment: Should I delete this question? I don't like down votes, even on meta

Comment: First, the downvotes are likely because of the clarity issues your question has. (It's a bit more confusing now, since you've edited your suggestion in.) Second, you can't delete it- There's an upvoted answer. If you start from what you _originally_ asked and just clarify _that part_ that you meant the close reason and not the actual migration, then your question will be a lot clearer. (And less broad, as you'll have only one question.)

Comment: It's more likely to be closed as "unclear" or "too broad" actually...

Comment: @Laurel it will block you when you get to the final step.  Your last edit really wasn't all that good.  You should go back to something much closer to your original post, only clarify which flag you were using.  Right now it is still a jumbled mess with a title that doesn't fit anything.

Comment: I hate the menus. I flagged a mod because there's no way I can change anything and keep sense of the comments and answer.

Comment: @Laurel I wouldn't worry about the comments.  Comments are easily cleaned up.  If you want to fix the question, just bring it back to the original version, and clean up the "migration" stuff as best you can.  The question and answer will make a lot more sense.  Or just wait to see if a mod will delete it.

Answer (score 7):

> Should I use the "Belongs on SuperUser" flag reason on crap that I think should just be deleted? Or another reason entirely? Theoretically, if the entire question was edited, it could be a valuable Super User question. Obviously, nobody's going to edit it, so am I wasting people's time flagging like this?

Exactly; migrating such a post is simply a waste of time for everyone involved. Although the migration will inevitably be rejected, you would already have two copies of the same post that need to be deleted, which is twice the work for users/moderators on both sites. No need for that when you can just delete the content on the spot.

My rule of thumb when it comes to migrations is to only even *consider* migration **if the post is good enough in the first place**. (I see users recommending migrations or cross-posts so often, that sometimes I get the impression that some of those people actually honestly think the posts are good enough. And that frightens me.)

I'm not a big fan of having canned close reasons that suggest alternative sites. They're *basically* a poor man's "belongs on [site]", but if a question is good enough to survive on a site where it belongs then presumably it should be migrated — and if it's *not* good enough, then recommending the site without advising the user that they *need* to improve their question is just as counter-productive as actually migrating the crap IMO, because most askers respond to that by copying and pasting their question virtually unmodified on the new site.

Comment: See my edited question. I didn't realize that I wasn't actually suggesting migration.

Comment: @Laurel what exactly are you asking now?  Seems like you answered your own question with an edit.